# MVC Web API POST request not working from client application but working from chrome Postman extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a web API service with the controller as follows.

```
RoutePrefix("api/Product")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [POST("InsertProduct")]
    public HttpResponseMessage InsertProduct(ProductDetail product)
    {
        //logic
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [GET("Item/{itemId}/{itemtypeid}")]
    public List<ProductDetail> GetProduct(int itemId, long itemtypeid)
    {
    //logic
        return response;
    }
}
```

Here the **GET** request is working from both **Postman tool**(chrome Rest service tester url) and also from the **client**(refer below). The **POST** request works fine with the Postman tool. But when I try the same code from the client i am getting the following error
"**StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'**".

The client code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/ProductService/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ProductDetail());
        StringContent stringContent = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(serializedContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<ProductDetail>("api/Product/InsertProduct", new ProductDetail()).Result;
```

How does the same requst works from any external tool but not work from httpclient.

Please help me with this.